# How to create a Spark button with an icon (left) and a label (center) in Flex 4.5?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

I would like to have a Spark Button in Flex, with a width of 180 pixels, an icon on the left and a centered label.

Something like this:

```
| -- icon -------- label -------------- |
```

At the moment, I have this:

```
<s:Button width="180" label="Login" icon="@Embed(source='icons/login.png')" />
```

But then the icon is also centered, just as the label.

Is it possible what I want?

Comment: Can't you create a custom button skin to do this?

Comment: Time to do some research.  Start here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS460ee381960520ad-2811830c121e9107ecb-7fff.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a custom skin for the spark button. There you can set the icon as your wish.